# Prove using the definition of a limit that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}|x|=1$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

Prove $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}|x|=1$$ using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit.

I know that we need to choose an $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\epsilon\}$ however, I don't understand why $\frac{1}{2}$ needs to be chosen and why we can't just choose $\delta=\varepsilon$. Is it possible to also pick $\delta \leq 1$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: If $\delta=\varepsilon$ and $|x-1|<\delta$, can you prove that $\big||x|-1\big| < \varepsilon$? If you can, then you are correct.

Comment: It is impossible to answer why $1/2$ is there since, as the answer below shows, it is not needed.

Comment: "we need to choose an $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\epsilon\}$" This is not correct. It is no doubt that this $\delta$ is a possible choice for establishing the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ property. However, the use of reverse triangle inequality (as in the answer below) reveals that $\frac{1}{2}$ is rather redundant. The choice $\delta = \epsilon$ perfectly works. I guess whoever came up with this choice tried to demonstrate a routine approach of 'restricting the range of $x$ as small as we wish until all good properties about the function become available'.

Comment: @SangchulLee Got it, thanks! Do you think you could explain why they chose $\frac{1}{2}$ when in other problems I've usually picked the value as just 1?

Comment: I have no good idea as to why $\frac{1}{2}$ is used there, as the choice $1$ will equally work as you pointed out. My humble guess is that the writer tried to teach students that the choice need not be optimal (so you need not spend time finding the optimal condition). This is also what I often do when I teach analysis, where I often use generic numbers something as $\frac{1}{42}$ or $\frac{1}{2021}$ to emphasize this.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you so much for your help! That cleared up so much :)

Comment: In many cases we do need a minimum of $\epsilon$ and some number,  because we are using an inequality that is only true if we are sufficiently close  (Like $x^n<x$ for $0<x<1$, so if we want to prove $x^n$ is continuous at $c$,  we want to make sure that we are within both $1$ and $\epsilon$ of $c$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: use the relation
$$\big||x|-1\big|\le|x-1|.$$

Comment: So I would just do: $$||x|-1| \leq |x-1| < \epsilon$$?

Comment: about the choice of $\frac{1}{2}$? it is related to the proximity of $x$ from $1$ you consider to seek approximations, but, as Arctic Char observes it is not needed.

Comment: so it is just a crude choice? I could have picked like $\frac{1}{5}$ if I wanted to?

Comment: Yes, you take $x$ so close to $1$ to guaranty  that $|x-1|<\epsilon$

Comment: also yes, any initial approximation is worth it

Comment: oh is this because x cannot equal 1, so we have to pick a a value close to 1?

Comment: $x$ can be $1$ in your example, but for a little more difficult one, like $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ you will have $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=2$ but $f(1)$ is not defined, even that $|f(x)-2|$ can be made as little as you want if $|x-1|$ is small enough.

Comment: thank you for all your help!!!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition**

Let $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be the modulus function.

Then for every pair of real numbers $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, one has that
\begin{align*}
||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|
\end{align*}

**Proof**

According to the triangle inequality, we can say that
\begin{align*}
|x| = |x - y + y| \leq |x - y| + |y| \Rightarrow |x| - |y| \leq |x - y|
\end{align*}

Similarly, $|y| - |x| \leq |x - y|$.

Hence $|x - y| \geq \max\{|x| - |y|, |y| - |x|\} = ||x| - |y||$.

**Solution**

Based on the previous proposition, we can prove a more general result.

That is to say: the function $|\cdot|$ is continuous for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Indeed, let $|x - a| < \delta$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
|x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow ||x| - |a|| \leq |x - a| < \delta := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Consequently, we conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \varepsilon$ such that
\begin{align*}
|x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow ||x| - |a|| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!